# Jquery "hide" without animation

Tags: jquery, animation, onclick, hide

I am trying to hide a div on click with no animation. This is my code:

```html
<script>
$('.open-menu').click(function(e){    
    $('#menulink').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#menu, #menu-background').toggle('slide');
    });
});

$('#menu-background').click(function(e){    
    $('#menu, #menu-background').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#menulink').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

The desired action is when you click #menu-background it hides itself with #menu, then #menulink appears again. This I have accomplished, but I want it to hide with no fade or animation. Just to disappear on click. With .hide it still animated and with .fadeOut('0') it still fades.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

How about using css ?

```
// hide immediately.
$("#hide-me").css("display", "none");

// show immediately.
$("#show-me").css("display", "initial");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want animations, just use .hide() or .show() without parameters instead of fadeout() or fadein().

```
<script>
$('.open-menu').click(function(e){    
    $('#menulink').hide();
    $('#menu, #menu-background').show();
});

$('#menu-background').click(function(e){    
    $('#menu, #menu-background').hide();
    $('#menulink').show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I just want no animation when hiding the divs if that is possible in any way?

Comment: Yes but it has no animation on everything.Trying to toggle in - but no animation when hiding.